# Embedding websites inside a shell application using Angular 2.0.0

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

In the project, I'm working on we have 4 individual websites and one shell to host all. The team is using Angular 2.0.0. Their approach they choose is embedding each website inside shell application (Using object tag). So that the Dom in high level look like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <object type="text/html" data="http://website1.com/#/" style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            Content of the Website 1
        </body>
    </html>
</object>
</body>
<html>
```

I am working as a FE dev and to me, this sounds so wrong! why? because I have html { with: 100%, width: 100% } and because we have 2 html tag nested it ruins the style. I believe there must be a better to just embed the content of the websites1. 
Would you please give me your thoughts about the best way to do this and potentially not having 2 html and body tags nested.

I'd appreciate

Comment: Nested `<html>` tags is  [**invalid markup**](https://validator.w3.org). What reason does your team have for embedding websites within other websites? Surely you could just insert a segment of the site, rather than the whole site itself. If you **need** the whole website displayed in two locations, why not just point two URLs to the same website?

Comment: They want to have 4 individual websites (Which from my point of view its 4 modules) but each website is managed/developed with a separate team. and each should plug into a shell application. so basically when clicking on the shell application menu it loads different websites.

Comment: Why not just have one website with four different isolated sections? Then each team can work on a different section (or component) of the website as a whole. You can even hook them up to different version control repositories.

Comment: You are right.But they want to have the ability to take out each website and deploy it somewhere else! They also asked me if it's an invalid markup why all JS is still working?!!!

Comment: @NeginBasiri I would suggest you to create 2 different angular application. You can  bootstrap multiple applications whenever you want. Refer these links - [Link1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169333/A-Note-on-Angular-Bootstrap-Multiple-Apps) and [Link2](https://blog.sstorie.com/bootstrapping-multiple-angular-2-applications-on-the-same-page/)

Comment: Thanks @Sanket. Sounds like a good solution.